# Un-(adjective) but In-(noun) -- does it ever go the other way?

Tags: etymology, negation, prefixes, negative-prefixes

Many pairs of words use un- as a prefix for the preferred adjective but in- as a prefix for the preferred noun (e.g. unstable/instability, unequal/inequality, unable/inability, unjust/injustice, ungrateful/ingratitude).

I was wondering if anyone has encountered the reverse phenomenon?  Where the in- is a prefix for the preferred adjective but un- is the prefix for the preferred noun?  If not, any explanations?

Comment: Note that all these nouns were borrowed from Latin, which used the _in_- negative. These adjectives, on the other hand, developed from the nouns in English and take the English _un_- negative. There are plenty of native English pairs like _unhappy/unhappiness_, as well as borrowed Latin pairs like _ingrate/ingratitude_.

Comment: I.e, it doesn't matter whether it's a noun or an adjective; what matters is whether it's native or borrowed.

Comment: invaluable is an in-adjective without a noun.

Comment: I believe one of the reasons one does not see many adjectives with *in-* prefixes for negation is that there is the confusing alternative of *in-* as an emphasizing (morphological) unit.  For example, both *inflammable* and *flammable* describe something which is capable of burning, the former more so than the latter.

Comment: @JohnLawler I'd consider your two comments a satisfactory answer - that it's about the origin of the word rather than its role in a sentence, the difference between Latin and Germanic words.

Comment: uninteresting and DISinterest

Comment: @JohnLawler: "...it doesn't matter whether it's a noun or an adjective" -- well, to be frank, I was really hoping for an example of the reverse phenomenon from anyone who was going to assert that part of speech didn't matter.  But oh, well, I guess we can speak theoretically.  I think you present a false dichotomy; the part of speech used could be LINKED to whether it is native or borrowed.  There could be a shared, recurring pathway that multiple words followed as one particular part of speech was blocked by an existing native word.

Comment: [Occam](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/OccamsRazor.pdf) would suggest that POS is a "plurality" (i.e, a non-terminal abstraction) that is "posited without necessity". You can assume that any abstraction you like is "linked to" whether a word is native or borrowed. But what's the benefit of that additional step? And how can its output be distinguished from that of the simpler hypothesis?

Comment: If you are reasoning from a false dichotomy, Occam won't help you.  I am inquiring, not advocating, so I am not sure what assumptions you are claiming I made.  I am still confused whether your answer is "yes" or "no" so would you kindly be more specific?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The only case I can come up with is [ingrate](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ingrate#Adjective)/[ungratefulness](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/ungratefulness). According to wiktionary, *ingrate* can be used as an adjective, they quote no lesser source than Shakespeare:

> But I will lift the down-trod Mortimer / As high in the air as this unthankful king, / As this ingrate and canker'd Bolingbroke. — William Shakespeare, King Henry IV, Part 1

So, even though *ingrate* is more often used as a noun, it can be an adjective and if coupled with *ungratefulness* breaks your rule.

Comment: Yes!  Archaic but a perfect example of the phenomenon going the other way.  Great find.